# По нажатию EditText разметка смещается

Tags: android

У меня есть `RelativeLayout` где находиться разные `View` - есть `EditText`, под ним `Button`. По нажатию `EditText` появляется клавиатура  и поднимается `EditText` и `Button`. К

Как сделать что `Button` не поднималось?

Comment: Поэкспериментируйте с флагом `android:windowSoftInputMode` в манифесте у нужной активити. Одно из его возможных значений точно решит проблему, но я не помню, какое именно http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
```